# vuejs vue-cli how can I use console.log without getting any errors

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am trying to see what is the content of the result variable.

```
const result = await axios.post('/login', {
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
});
console.log(result);
```

after I run "npm run serve"

I receive an error failed to compile for using console.

[image]

is there a way to use console when using vue-cli?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366773/how-enable-console-log-in-vue-cli-during-development

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you generated this project with the CLI and used default settings, check your `.eslintrc.js` file. The rules will be in there. You'll see something like:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
}
```

Altering the `extends` and `rules` will do what you're wanting.

Additionally, you can use the `// eslint-disable-next-line` or `/* eslint-disable */` comments to ignore areas that contains `console.log()`.

If the file is missing, create it in the root and add:

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        'no-console': 'off',
    },
};
```

Comment: I dont have any .eslintrc.js when I created the project. should I create .eslintrc.js inside the src/ directory or in the root folder

Comment: Yes, create the .eslintrc.js in the root and add the rule. I'll update the answer.