# How can I enable the console log in VUE-CLI during development

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, eslint, console.log, vue-cli-3

I have been trying to figure out how to `console.log('whatever')` (while learning some Vue.js development) in my methods in order to understand some behaviour of whatever I am doing here.

I understand that there are some questions already asked here and have looked at the **ESLINT** documentation to try and figure this out... I just can't actually understand what I should do.

My code:

```
methods: {
    submitData() {
        this.$http.post('https://vue-testing-8a2de.firebaseio.com/data.json', this.user)
                  .then(response => {
                            console.log(response);
                        }, error => {
                            console.log(error)
                        })
    }
}
```

This is the error on ESLINT:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: Unexpected console statement (no-console) at src/App.vue:35:22:
  33 | this.$http.post('https://vue-testing-8a2de.firebaseio.com/data.json',this.user)
  34 |           .then(response => {
> 35 |                      console.log(response);
     |                      ^
  36 |                  }, error => {
  37 |                      console.log(error)
  38 |                  })


error: Unexpected console statement (no-console) at src/App.vue:37:22:
  35 |                      console.log(response);
  36 |                  }, error => {
> 37 |                      console.log(error)
     |                      ^
  38 |                  })
  39 |             }
  40 |         }


2 errors found.
```

I have looked at this website:

- https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console

I tried commenting the previous line before `console.log`:

- `/*eslint no-console: "error"*/` (but it doesn't works well)

I need a step by step guide if I need to mess with JSON rules, as I have never done this before.

I am using `vue-cli` on WebStorm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: based on [this vue-cli github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2266) it's as simple as adding `rules:{
            "no-console": "off"
        }` to the eslintConfig section of *your* `package.json` - there's more info in the issue linked to show how to strip `console` completely from production output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366773/how-enable-console-log-in-vue-cli-during-development

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit `package.json` and in eslintConfig property add

```
"eslintConfig": { // don't add this, it's already there
    // there's stuff here
    "rules": { // find the rules property
    // addition starts here
        "no-console": "off"
    // addition ends here
    },
    // and keep what was already here
```

Now, if you want console.log stripped from production build

Edit `vue.config.js`

and add

```
// addition starts here
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
// addition ends here

module.exports = {
    // addition starts here
    configureWebpack: {
        optimization: {
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: isProd ? [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    terserOptions: {
                        ecma: 6,
                        compress: { drop_console: true },
                        output: { comments: false, beautify: false }
                    }
                })
            ] : []
        }
    },
    // addition ends here
    // and keep what was already here
}
```

Comment: I have looked for the ```package.json``` file and I found the one located in the following path ```my-project/package.json```. I have placed the code on the location you've specified and it still returns an error. I have improvised the ```json.file``` and the new ```ESLINT``` error on the folling FIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/alioshr/72g0hpnm/3/

Comment: you added just the THREE lines `"rules": {
        "no-console": "off"
    },` ??? exactly within `"eslintConfig": {`???

Comment: please check the complete ```json.file``` on the fiddle I have just added above. I have copied the whole file into JS part in order to show that I have added the lines indeed. Could you please take a look whenever you can?

Comment: see how you have a second set of `rules: {}` ... sorry, my bad, didn't realies `rules` already existed in package.json

Comment: my bad that I was so dumb that I did not see it as well. I have just followed you answer again and now it worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

1 Edit package.json

2 Then find "rules": {}

3 Change to this        "rules":{"no-console":0}

4 if you Vue server in on, off it and run it again. Then the issue will be done

Answer (score -1):

Just use console.table(value) or console.info(value)
instead of console.log(value)