# How can I make console.log() work in a Vue-cli app?

Tags: console.log, vue-cli

I am trying to add a console.log() call in my vue-cli app to support debugging.  Here's an excerpt from my template

```
      <v-btn v-on:click.native="console.log('start button clicked')" 
      color="primary rounded-pill">
        Start
      </v-btn>
```

However, when I run the app on *localhost*, I get the following message in the console:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Property or method "console"
> is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure
> that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for
> class-based components, by initializing the property.

I reviewed [How enable console log in VUE-CLI during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366773/how-enable-console-log-in-vue-cli-during-development), but it didn't seem to apply to my case, as I am not using eslint, and there is no eslintConfig section in my package.json file.

Any idea what else could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try adding "this" so it would look like: this.console.log()
2. just make a vue method and call it on click

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I couldn't get it to work with your first idea, but the second one (putting the console.log into a separate method) worked.

Comment: Going forward, though, I should probably learn how to use the Chrome debugger instead of spreading console.log() statements all over the place, as it seems to be best practice.

Comment: I would suggest downloading Vue extension on chrome, try to understand how it works and it'll make ur life easier